# Add one day to date in cells using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro set up that will clear content on a spreadsheet.  At the end of this Macro, I want to select specific cells that already have dates in them and then replace the current dates with current date +1.  After searching the web I found the DateAdd function, but I am pretty new to VBA and I am having difficulty writing the function correctly.  After selecting the necessary cells, how would I go about changing the dates to the next day?

Answer (score 7):

Taking your question literally, you could do this:

```
' Here goes the code where you select the date cells you want to increment
' ...
' Now increment them by 1 day:
Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In Selection
    cell.Value = cell.Value + 1 ' adds 1 day
Next cell
```

The unit of the Date data type is a day. So adding 1 adds one day.

Answer (score 5):

Here's an example of how to use DateAdd:

```
Range("A1").value = DateAdd("d", 1, CDate(Range("A1")))
```

This, of course, assumes a valid date is in A1. It will increment that date by a single day.

"d" means we are adding a day. Here are the other intervals for adding years, months, etc.

yyyy - Year

q - Quarter

m - Month

y - Day of year

d - Day

w - Weekday

ww - Week

h - Hour

n - Minute

s - Second

Notice I use CDate. That simply converts the value of range("a1") into a date. It will throw an error if A1 cannot be parsed as a date.

Of course, you can also use this method to subtract days:

```
Range("A1").value = DateAdd("d", -3, CDate(Range("A1")))
```

This subtracts three days for the date in A1.

Answer (score 2):

If you have date in cell a1 and want increment one day, it should be as simple as

`range("a1").value = range("a1").value + 1`