# VBA - Copy and Paste with increment

Tags: vba, excel

Hi i need help on creating a VBA to copy range of cells repeatedly with one column having increments.

Current data

[image]

Expected Output

[image]

I found a vba but will only copy the rows based on column C without increments on the date

[Excel VBA automation - copy row "x" number of times based on cell value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25395454/excel-vba-automation-copy-row-x-number-of-times-based-on-cell-value)

Comment: What have you tried? What has/hasn't worked? Also can you clarify your issue?  It looks like you could just create a table with a date per row, no? or is it for each unique date in your current data, you want a row in the output?

Comment: Put the actual text in the question - helps with searching for answers.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you would need to do this as excel has built-pattern pattern recognition for these scenarios, after entering two succesive dates if you hover over and click the border of the cell then drag down, the desired date range will appear in the column automatically.

If you still insist on doing this programatically for whatever reason then your question already has multiply feasible solutions here: [Add one day to date in cells using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8156271/add-one-day-to-date-in-cells-using-vba)

Specify each cell in turn then increment the value by the corresponding row number to return desired date range in column A:

```
          Range("A2").Value = Range("A2").Value + 2 ' add 2 days
          Range("A3").Value = Range("A3").Value + 3 ' add 3 days
          Range("A4").Value = Range("A4").Value + 4 ' add 4 days

          '-------- So on and so forth until desired range is acheived --------'
```

or alternatively:

```
           Range("A2").value = DateAdd("d", 2, CDate(Range("A2")))
           Range("A3").value = DateAdd("d", 3, CDate(Range("A3")))
```

Speaking as someone who had to learn the hard way, please take my advice and ensure you research your problem thouroughly to find a solution before posting. Refer to the guidelines [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/advice?) if needed.